# How to make MS Access run a query on focus lose event and take actions accordingly

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am creating a small Access DB for our Data Entry guys. Our main DB is mysql but due to ease of use we are creating an Access DB to make it easier for them to enter the Data. I have done most of it but am stuck with this problem (which I know how to solve in mysql+php) Please pardon my ignorance, but I have just started using MS Access.

I have two tables - ClientPhones and sales. The ClientPhones table has phone, clientid fields. sales table has salesid, clientid, date, etc fields.

I also have a Form which has all relevant fields for the sales table. I want to add a new field, phone_no in that form. When a user inputs the number and on focus lose event, I was access to run a query on the clients table to see if the phone number exists in any of the 3 phone number fields. If it finds a client with that phone number, the client ID should be populated, else a new form to input the client details should be shown.

Is this possible with MS access or am I doing this incorrectly?

Comment: Given that clients table design, how do you ensure a specific phone number is associated with only one client?

Comment: if while entering the client record, we always check for duplicate phone numbers, the table will always have 1 phone number associated with 1 client. Basically the data entry person will not have the option to select a different client if a phone number match is found. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: phone1, phone2, phone3 fields seems like suboptimal design to me.  I would store phone numbers in a related table with clientid and a single phone field.  That table would contain separate records for each of the client's phone numbers.  A unique index on the phone field absolutely prevents duplicates.  And that design makes it trivially easy to lookup the clientid based on a given phone number.

Comment: Well, that can be done. I understand what you mention, however this is how the company had their primary DB created earlier. Changing it would break some things. But yeah for the Access DB we can definitely do that.

Comment: @HansUP Edited the table structure. Now I have a table called ClientPhones with two columns - clientid and phone. This is the statement that works: `PARAMETERS input_phone Text (255); SELECT c.clientid FROM ClientPhones AS c WHERE c.phone = [input_phone];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the text box's After Update event to retrieve the *clientid* which matches the phone number the user entered.

If a *clientid* is found, store it in the text box which is bound to *clientid*.

If no match is found, ask whether the user wants to add a new client, and open that form if they respond yes.

This code outline assumes *txtSearchPhone* is the name of the text box where the user enters the target phone number, and *txtClientId* is the name of the text box where you want to store *clientid*.

```vb
Private Sub txtSearchPhone_AfterUpdate()
    Dim varClientId As Variant
    Dim strCriteria As String

    strCriteria = "[phone]='" & Me.txtSearchPhone.Value & "'"
    Debug.Print strCriteria '<-- inspect this in Immediate window; Ctrl+g will take you there
    varClientId = DLookup("clientid", "ClientPhones", strCriteria)
    If IsNull(varClientId) Then
        If MsgBox("Add new user?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            'DoCmd.OpenForm ... (see Access help topic)
        End If
    Else
        Me.txtClientId.Value = varClientId
    End If
End Sub
```

Make sure the text in *txtSearchPhone* does not include a single quote character (`'`) because the `DLookup` will break if it does.  You can use the text box's Validation Rule and/or Before Update event to make sure a single quote is not present.